# Adicionar restrição MYSQL

Tags: sql

Estou utilizando a seguinte query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` order by `account_id` ASC";
```

Como eu faço para adicionar uma restrição de quando a account_id for igual a 1 ele "pular" e não pegar os valores da linha com account_id = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diga que o ID não pode ser `1`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE account_id <> 1 order by `account_id` ASC";
```

Supondo que os IDs são todos positivos, também pode ser assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE account_id > 1 order by `account_id` ASC";
```

Comment: Perfeito haha. Eu estava tentando usar =! do php pois nao sabia o simbolo de diferente no MYSQL xD

Comment: O MySQL também aceita `!=` (como no PHP), mas isso não funcionaria em outros bancos. Sua tentativa não deu certo porque você inverteu a ordem dos caracteres!

Comment: aaaaa agora entendi. Muito obrigado :)